# How to add data with push

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying add data to an array, but using myArray.push() isn't working the way I want it to.
I am using a datagrid so the array has to be in the format

```
var tabledata:Array = [{'Column Name':'Something', 'Another Column':'More data'}];
```

but then adding to it using

```
tabledata.push([{'Column Name':'Something', 'Another Column':'More data'}]);
```

Doesn't seem to be working - it adds a row but doesn't add any data to the cells.

**Fixed it, just have to remove the square brackets in the push command

```
tabledata.push({'Column Name':'Something', 'Another Column':'More data'});
```

Comment: 'Column Name' should not be String

Comment: If you fixed it, post it as an answer or accept the current answer. It's pointless to edit your question with an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
var tabledata:Array = [{ColumnName:'Something', AnotherColumn:'More data'}];
myGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(tabledata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object in AS3.0 like this:

```
var object:Object= {ColumnNameA:'Something', AnotherColumnB:'More data'};
```

*notice how the property name (ColumnNameA& AnotherColumnB) is not within ''*

Then,

```
var tabledata:Array= new Array();

tabledata.push(object);
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: hi!, did you find my answer useful?